# Why do String.prototype.match() return two elements when string only has one unique match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I cant understand why this code snippet return an array on two strings "BEARING" instead of only a string "BEARING. Any ideas?

```js
const cleanedString = "ANGULAR CONTACT (ROLLING) BEARING"

const noun = cleanedString.match(/\b(\w+)$/);
console.log(noun);
```

Comment: Two matches: 1st match `\b(\w+)$`, 2nd match `(w+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the global `/g` flag:

```js
const cleanedString = "ANGULAR CONTACT (ROLLING) BEARING"

const noun = cleanedString.match(/\b(\w+)$/g);
console.log(noun);
```

From [String.prototype.match() *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, str.match() will return the same result as RegExp.exec().

Comment: Glad to help :).

Answer (score 1):

It returns an array of 2 which signify

1. Full Match of the string
2. String matched in the first capturing group

You can make it a non capturing group by

```js
const cleanedString = "ANGULAR CONTACT (ROLLING) BEARING"

const noun = cleanedString.match(/\b(?:\w+)$/);
console.log(noun);
```

where **?:** signifies that the group would be non capturing

Answer (score 1):

By default match returns the string that matched as the first value.

By putting parens in your regex, you asked for a part of the matched string to be returned (which happens to be the same in this case).

So if your regex had been this:

```
/^(\w+).*\b(\w+)$/
```

You would have 3 strings returned

1. The whole string
2. ANGULAR
3. BEARING